# Trie for Longest Prefix Match

Tags: networking, data-structures, routes, trie, routetable

Suppose I have a route_table_entry structure with these fields:

```
typedef struct route_table_entry {
    uint32_t prefix;
    uint32_t next_hop;
    uint32_t mask;
    int interface;
} route_table_entry;
```

And I want to build a Trie for the Longest Prefix Match algorithm like this:

```
typedef struct trie {
    route_table_entry *entry;
    bool end;
    struct trie *child;
    struct trie *sibling;
} Trie;
```

Well, I'm not sure If that's actually the best way to store this, but what should I store in the Trie? How would I take in account that I get the maximum mask? First I did this with a routing_table structure that was sorted for the prefix and then decreasing for the mask and with a binary search that would be easy to find. But with a Trie how is it taken in account that I get the prefix with the highest mask when searching for the prefix?

Comment: Cisco has a pretty good explanation of the data structures it uses for the different methods it uses: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/express-forwarding-cef/13706-20.html "_Cisco Express Forwarding, also uses a 256 way data structure to store forwarding and MAC header rewrite information, but it does not use a tree. Cisco Express Forwarding uses a trie, which means the actual information being searched for is not in the data structure; instead, the data is stored in a separate data structure, and the trie simply points to it._"

Comment: @RonMaupin Hello, I've read the explanations but I still don't see where it's taken in account the mask?